# "What do i do 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to create a small database application for my college but I seem to be having some issues with the login page. If I enter a username and password that exists in my Access database then everything works fine, however, if I enter a username and password that's not there, the application throws me this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'

I want it to show me my `Else` msgbox saying that I've entered invalid details. I'd really appreciate the help. P.s I'm new to this, and hope I used the correct format for this question. I'm using Visual Basic and an Access database.

```vb
stringPass = frmProgressBar.stringRecieve

provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
dataFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\RGIT\College\Semester 2 Assignments\Programming\College.accdb"
connString = provider & dataFile

myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
myConnection.Open()

Dim str As String
str = "Select * from Users where Username = @Username and Password = @Password"

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", CType(txtUserName.Text, String))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", CType(txtPassword.Text, String))

Dim adaptor As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()

adaptor.Fill(table)

If txtUserName.Text = Nothing Or txtPassword.Text = Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Fill in all fields", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    myConnection.Close()
Else
    If (txtUserName.Text) = (table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()) And (txtPassword.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()) Then
        If (table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()) = "Admin" Then
            stringPass = "Admin"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        ElseIf (table.Rows.Count > 0) And (table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()) = "Employee" Then
            stringPass = "Employee"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        Else
            stringPass = "Student"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Login Unsuccessful, unregistered username or incorrect password entered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtUserName.Clear()
        txtUserName.Focus()
        myConnection.Close()
        table.DataSet.Clear()
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the offending line:

```
If (txtUserName.Text) = (table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()) And (txtPassword.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()) Then
```

I suggest inserting a check of the number of available table rows before that line. You have a check later on, move that line further up.

```
table.Rows.Count > 0
```

Using your own code, with the check inserted:

```
If txtUserName.Text = Nothing Or txtPassword.Text = Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Fill in all fields", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    myConnection.Close()
ElseIf (table.Rows.Count < 1) Then
    MsgBox("Login Unsuccessful, unregistered username or incorrect password entered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    txtPassword.Clear()
    txtUserName.Clear()
    txtUserName.Focus()
    myConnection.Close()
    table.DataSet.Clear()
Else
    If (txtUserName.Text) = (table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()) And (txtPassword.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()) Then
        If (table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()) = "Admin" Then
            stringPass = "Admin"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        ElseIf (table.Rows.Count > 0) And (table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()) = "Employee" Then
            stringPass = "Employee"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        Else
            stringPass = "Student"
            Me.Visible = False
            frmProgressBar.Visible = True
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Login Unsuccessful, unregistered username or incorrect password entered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtUserName.Clear()
        txtUserName.Focus()
        myConnection.Close()
        table.DataSet.Clear()
    End If
End If'''
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for the assistance. I actually tried that. When i do, it either throws the same error or the button doesnt work at all. Do you think its the way i wrote the code? structure, or syntax or something?

Comment: @ASHTON I updated my answer, inserting a new rows check a bit further up. Try this.

Comment: That worked like a charm, bro. Thank you so much. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Keep you User Interface and DataAccess methods separate. I used a Structure for the return type of ValidateLogin. This could also be a Class or a Tuple. (You probably haven't been introduced to Tuples yet) This allows me to return 2 different datatypes.

Keep you database objects local to the data access method so you can control that they are closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks will handle this for you even it there is an error. You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the select string and connection directly to the constructor of the command.

You do not need to retrieve the data only the check if a matching record exists. One way to do that is using the database's count method.

Good job using Parameters but don't use .AddWithValue. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

You will have to check your database for the proper OleDbType and field size. I just guessed.

You do not have to convert a .Text property to a string; it is already a string.

Declare your DataTable outside of your Using blocks. So it can be used after the connection and command are closed and disposed.

```
Public Structure LoginData
    Public Sub New(loginType As String, Valid As Boolean)
        Type = loginType
        Success = Valid
    End Sub
    Public Type As String
    Public Success As Boolean
End Structure

Private Function ValidateLogin(User As String, PWord As String) As LoginData
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\RGIT\College\Semester 2 Assignments\Programming\College.accdb")
        'stringPass = frmProgressBar.stringRecieve
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select Count(*), LoginType From Users Where Username = @Username and Password = @Password;", myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = User
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = PWord
            myConnection.Open()
            table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    'The AndAlso Stops evaluating as soon as it finds a False
    'This prevents an error when we try to access Row 0 in the table when it doesn't exist
    If table.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso CInt(table(0)(0)) = 1 Then
        Return New LoginData(table(0)(1).ToString, True)
    Else
        Return New LoginData(Nothing, False)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Do the validation in the User Interface code
    'The OrElse is a smidge quicker because it stops as soon as it finds True
    If txtUserName.Text = Nothing OrElse txtPassword.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Fill in all fields", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Return
    End If
    Dim LD = ValidateLogin(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    If LD.Success Then
        MsgBox("Login Unsuccessful, unregistered username or incorrect password entered", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        txtPassword.Clear()
        txtUserName.Clear()
        txtUserName.Focus()
        Return
    End If
    stringPass = LD.Type
    Me.Visible = False
    frmProgressBar.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Notice how the User Interface code (The button click) knows nothing about the database and the database code knows nothing about the UI. This will allow you to begin tiers in you project; a data access tier separate from the UI tier.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that passwords should **NEVER** be stored as plain text. You should have been taught to salt and hash passwords before studying logins. I will leave that to you and your instructor to correct.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I clearly have a lot to learn. This was extremely helpful. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. Not great with VBA. However, what is `adaptor.Fill(table)` doing?

Before that, `table` is instantiated: `Dim table As New DataTable()` It's empty.

After the adaptor call, you say `If (txtUserName.Text) = (table.Rows(0)(2).ToString())`. But... what is `table`?

Something isn't working between all the connecting that the call to `adaptor` to assign something to the empty `table`.

One of these lines probably isn't working

```
Dim adaptor As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

Dim table As New DataTable()

adaptor.Fill(table)
```

Comment: hey...thank you so much for helping. I did try adding "Users" (which is the table name in the database) to the New datatable. example ...New DataTable("Users"). Still gives me the same error. I apologize, this is my first year coding. forgive the lack of proper terminology

Comment: VBA has some debugging areas (View->Immediate/locals/Watch). Turn those on. Comment out your code, and see if the first couple of lines work. For example `Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)` maybe should be two separate lines.

Comment: ok im going to give that a try...thanks again. will tell you if it worls

Comment: The problem is this line : "If (table.Rows.Count > 0) And (txtUserName.Text) = (table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()) And (txtPassword.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString())"

Comment: @VISQL The OP is using VB.NET. With that in mind, it's pretty clear what a [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) is and what [`DataAdapter.Fill()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8) does.

Comment: @GSerg, they are quite similar.